# Can I replace signed-in user using an older user uid in FireStore Anonymous Login?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

In my app, users are signed in anonymously. If someone uninstalls the app and re-installs it, the new generated uid is different from the older one. Is there some way I can revert the firebase auth instance to use the older uid instead of the new one?

Comment: You can't define custom UID, because signInAnonymously function is not supported. Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinanonymously

Comment: Can I somehow generate a token from the older firestore UID and use it to sign in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a user is signed out from Firebase's anonymous authentication provider, there is no way to reclaim that UID through that provider. Given that a user doesn't have to provide any credentials to sign-in anonymously, allowing them to claim a specific UID would be a big security risk.

The only option would be to [build your own provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for Firebase Authentication and give the user the same UID as before there, after you've verified that they *are* the same user.

Comment: I'm able to verify that UID1 is actually the same user as UID0 using firebase. But I cant seem to log into UID0 using Firebase SignIn methods. The custom token method as I understood is only generated for the already signedin user UID1, so that didnt help as well.

Comment: When generating a custom token **you** control the UID. See the code snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk. So that means you can generate a custom token for UID0. Alternatively you can "migrate" the data to the new UID of the user (changing the UIDs in your database), which is a common workaround for this problem.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that really helped. I'll try to figure out how to get that token without using admin access or write an API on the cloud.